# Is metasploit is a virus?

Tags: windows, windows-10, metasploit

When I opened the metasploit exe from the official website, Windows security spammed me with notifications "Issues found" and when I looked the files marked where Trojans from the actual GitHub I searched one file, and it was a PowerShell.

The thing is, it is the official website, so I
thought it was safe and I scanned it
with malwarebytes and Windows
Defender before running it and
VirusTotal.

So, I think it was a bug that
windows security thought it
was a Trojan because
maybe it was code to
make a Trojan.

So why did it
happen and
what should
I do?

BTW, afterwards I
scanned
my system
and found
no virus.

Comment: By its nature metasploit is detected as a hack tool (which it is), and Defender will flag it as malicious.

Comment: Metasploit comes in regular and commercial (with support) downloads for installation. If you are new to this, you might consider the supported model so you can get help from the software vendor. I have the regular model as part of my Kali installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metasploit is a hacking tool. These tools, even though they are not by nature viruses, are considered as dangerous to victims of attacks.

So, it is natural that Windows Defender warned you of it.  Once again, it is NOT a virus, it is a hacking tool.  It is harmless to you provided you uninstalled everything (even registry keys) related to it.

Comment: So, do I just tell windows defender to shut up?

Comment: Oh totally. Windows defender is like those people who just can't handle being ignored.